# Name and IP Virtual Host on Apache

Tags: apache

I am trying to direct web traffic for our domain to a Vhost site and our internal web site to separate directory that is only accessible within our private network,i.e 192.168.x.x.

I have modified Vhost configuration on Apache to include a name-based Vhost for the external website and a IP Vhost for the Intranet. No far I have had no luck, Apache does not like it.

Here is my modified Vhost config file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "/home/webs">
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/webs/foo
    ServerName www.foo.com
    ServerAlias foo.com
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/webs/foo/error.log
    CustomLog /home/webs/foo/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.*:80

<Directory "/home/webs/OffCat">
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.*:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/webs/OffCat
    ServerName 192.168.0.15/OffCat
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/webs/OffCat/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/webs/OffCat/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Tony Cripps

Comment: How exactly does Apache show its disapproval?

Comment: Nothing runs, i.e. neither site works with that configuration.

Comment: Well, I can think of several ways in which both sites are able to not run: Apache does not start and logs a syntax error, Apache returns an error HTTP status code, Apache serves the wrong site, the connection times out, the server explodes in flames... "Does not work" is not as useful and it's actually redundant because, if it worked, you would not be posting here.

Comment: Ok, more clearly, the public site worked before I modified the Vhost's config file for the private size, now neither work. But, you are correct,"Does not work" is not useful. When I can reboot the server, I will gather error data. Thanks..

Comment: The only error I see in the Apache error log, was an "No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /home/webs/OffCat/logs/error.log."  So, I created the logs directory and assigned ownership to daemons. Still, with that conf, getting "This page cannot be displayed".